# BeautifulSoup - why is it printing file path and not the content

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, filepath

I am trying to understand how BeautifulSoup works. Note that I am really new to Python so I am probably missing something out.

I open a Python terminal and write this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
ytchannel = '/home/XXX/Documents/test2'
soup = BeautifulSoup(ytchannel)
print(soup.prettify())
```

This is what I get:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   /home/XXX/Documents/test2
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Why? It makes no sense to me. I just want the content of `test2`.
I am writing exactly what is written on the BeautifulSoup website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed a string to `BeautifulSoup()`; sure it is a filename, but `BeautifulSoup()` does not open filenames for you. It operates on strings or open file-objects only.

Open the file first; `BeautifulSoup()` will read file objects if you pass those in:

```
with open(ytchannel) as infile:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(infile)
```

See [Making the soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup).